# Python 2.7 finding if some anagram of one string is a substring of another

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean, anagram

EDIT: Posting my final solution because this was a very helpful thread and I want to add some finality to it. Using the advice from both answers below I was able to craft a solution. I added a helper function in which I defined an anagram. Here is my final solution:

```
def anagram(s1, s2):
    s1 = list(s1)
    s2 = list(s2)
    s1.sort()
    s2.sort()
    return s1 == s2

def Question1(t, s):
    t_len = len(t)
    s_len = len(s)
    t_sort = sorted(t)
    for start in range(s_len - t_len + 1):
        if anagram(s[start: start+t_len], t):
            return True
    return False

print Question1("app", "paple")
```

---

I am working on some practice technical interview questions and I'm stuck on the following question:

`Find whether an anagram of string t is a substring of s`

I have worked out the following two variants of my code, and a solution to this I believe lies in a cross between the two. The problem I am having is that the first code always prints `False.`, regardless of input. The second variation works to some degree.  However, it cannot sort individual letters. For example `t=jks s=jksd` will print `True!` however `t=kjs s=jksd` will print `False.`

```
def Question1():
    # Define strings as raw user input.
    t = raw_input("Enter phrase t:")
    s = raw_input("Enter phrase s:")
    # Use the sorted function to find if t in s
    if sorted(t.lower()) in sorted(s.lower()):
        print("True!")
    else:
        print("False.")

Question1()
```

Working variant:

```
def Question1():
    # Define strings as raw user input.
    t = raw_input("Enter phrase t:")
    s = raw_input("Enter phrase s:")
    # use a loop to find if t is in s.
    if t.lower() in s.lower():
        print("True!")
    else:
        print("False.")

Question1()
```

I believe there is a solution that lies between these two, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use `sorted` in this situation.

Comment: you need to get all the combinations of chars in t and check them against s. it's not right to sort s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very much on the right track.  First, please note that there is no loop in your second attempt.

The problem is that you can't simply sort *all* of s and then look for sorted(t) in that.  Rather, you have to consider each len(t) sized substring of s, and check *that* against the sorted t.  Consider the trivial example:

```
t = "abd"
s = "abdc"
```

**s** trivially contains **t**.  However, when you sort them, you get the strings **abd** and **abcd**, and the **in** comparison fails.  The sorting gets other letters in the way.

Instead, you need to step through **s** in chunks the size of **t**.

```
t_len = len(t)
s_len = len(s)
t_sort = sorted(t)
for start in range(s_len - t_len + 1):
   chunk = s[start:start+t_len]
   if t_sort == sorted(chunk):
       # SUCCESS!!
```

Comment: Apparently there *is* one right way... ;-)

Comment: That was beautifully explained, thank you so much for simplifying this for me. I marked this as the answer for this question, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  You retroactively justify what I got paid when I was teaching.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem lies in the "substring" requirement. If you sort, you destroy order. Which means that while you can determine that an anagram of string1 is an anagram of a substring of string2, until you actually deal with string2 in order, you won't have a correct answer.

I'd suggest iterating over all the substrings of length `len(s1)` in `s2`. This is a straightforward for loop. Once you have the substrings, you can compare them (sorted vs sorted) with `s1` to decide if there is any rearrangement of `s1` that yields a contiguous substring of `s2`.

Viz:

```
s1 = "jks"
s2 = "aksjd"

print('s1=',s1, ' s2=', s2)
for offset in range(len(s2) - len(s1) + 1):
    ss2 = s2[offset:offset+len(s1)]
    if sorted(ss2) == sorted(s1):
        print('{} is an anagram of {} at offset {} in {}'.format(ss2, s1, offset, s2))
```

Comment: I just want to say that both of these answers were very helpful and its hard to pick just one correct one. Is there a way to select two answers? Fairly new to stack overflow

Comment: Nope. Just pick the "most helpful" one (which might be the one you read first) and move on. Plenty of karma lying around...